# Render google sign in Button in xamarin forms application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-signin

How can we render the google sign in button in xamarin.Android to be rendered in xamarin forms application. Is there any way we could achieve it without using the Auth url in xamarin forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can we render the google sign in button in xamarin.Android to be rendered in xamarin forms application. Is there any way we could achieve it without using the Auth url in xamarin forms.

I'm not sure your "Auth Url" indicates which method for authentication.

By android app, we can use google SDK to achieve this. Using `GoogleApiClient` to integrate google Sign-In into our app, first we need to install the package [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/), [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/) and [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/) into your android project and then you may take a look at this official doc: [Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in).

Since you're using Xamarin.Forms, you can create your custom sign-in button for example like this:

```
public class MySignInButton : Button
{
}
```

And renderer like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySignInButton), typeof(SignInButtonRenderer))]

namespace GoogleSignInApp.Droid
{
    public class SignInButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    var gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                                .RequestEmail()
                                .Build();

                    var mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder((FormsAppCompatActivity)Forms.Context)
                        .EnableAutoManage((FormsAppCompatActivity)Forms.Context, new OnConnectionFailedListener())
                        .AddApi(Android.Gms.Auth.Api.Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                        .Build();
                    Control.Click += (sender, ee) =>
                    {
                        var signInIntent = Android.Gms.Auth.Api.Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                        ((FormsAppCompatActivity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, 9001);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class OnConnectionFailedListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnConnectionFailedListener
    {
        public void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
        {
            Log.Debug("error", "error");
        }
    }
}
```

In xaml, you can use this button like this:

```
<local:MySignInButton Text="Sign In" />
```

**Don't forget** to add `<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" />` in android project's manifest.

I'm here using Custom Renderer cause you ask for rendering a sign-in button in your question, I guess you may also need to style your button or something like that, otherwise using [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) will be more professional in this scenario in my opinion.

And don't forget to implement the `OnActivityResult` of your `MainActivity` of android project. If any further questions, please leave a comment.

Comment: @Grace Feng - Finding hard, what to implement in the OnActivityResult. Can you post a sample code in Github so that others can refer?

Comment: @MobleJoseph, just check the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in), Xamarin.Android has similar implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these two examples [google authorization without webview](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow/) and [google authorization with webview](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/).It will be useful for you.

You can refer this code which helped me to do google sign in on button click.

```
void OnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string clientId = null;
        string redirectUri = null;

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                clientId = Constants.iOSClientId;
                redirectUri = Constants.iOSRedirectUrl;
                break;

            case Device.Android:
                clientId = Constants.AndroidClientId;
                redirectUri = Constants.AndroidRedirectUrl;
                break;
        }

        var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId,
            null,
            Constants.Scope,
            new Uri(Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
            new Uri(redirectUri),
            new Uri(Constants.AccessTokenUrl),
            null,
            true);

        authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
        authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;

        AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

        var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
        presenter.Login(authenticator);
    }

    async void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
        if (authenticator != null)
        {
            authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
            authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
        }

        User user = null;
        if (e.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // If the user is authenticated, request their basic user data from Google
            // UserInfoUrl = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
            var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri(Constants.UserInfoUrl), null, e.Account);
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            if (response != null)
            {
                // Deserialize the data and store it in the account store
                // The users email address will be used to identify data in SimpleDB
                string userJson = await response.GetResponseTextAsync();
                user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(userJson);
            }

            if (account != null)
            {
                store.Delete(account, Constants.AppName);
            }

            await store.SaveAsync(account = e.Account, Constants.AppName);
            await DisplayAlert("Email address", user.Email, "OK");
        }
    }

    void OnAuthError(object sender, AuthenticatorErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
        if (authenticator != null)
        {
            authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
            authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Authentication error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Is it ok now @geisterfurz007